# HTML "POST" without "GET"

Tags: html, browser, push-notification

Do modern browsers (with Javascript) support any means so I can "push" content into them, or notify them about a change so they can re-query a page only if needed?

Objective is: user has queried a page, which displays data. Now the underlying data changes, and I'd like the page, if it is still open in the user's browser, to update, without using client based polling mechanisms.

Can this be technically done, and if yes, any link where I can read more about it would be great.

Comment: Yes, that's what websockets are for. Stackoverflow also uses them.

Comment: You can also take a look on Server sent events: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp

Comment: HTML5 Server-Sent Events ... looked promising, but alas, I checked the "browser support" table, and there it says: "Internet Explorer" - not supported --> K.O.